# Keyboard setup in a KVM configuration

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, kde, kvm-switch

I'm using a Fedora 16 notebook and a Windows 7 desktop at work. The notebook stays turned on and closed under the desk and I use the desktop's display and keyboard. To switch between desktop and notebook I use a KVM. In Gnome I can switch between the notebook and desktop and both the display and keyboard configurations are correct.

In KDE 4.8 the display is also working as expected. But I can't configure the keyboard to the desktop's Brazilian ABNT one. I mean it accepts the key presses from the desktop keyboard but keeps stuck to the notebook's US international layout. I tried the configuration screens without success. That is the only thing keeping me away from KDE on the notebook. At home I'm a happy KDE user in my Fedora 17 desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove and read all the layouts for it to work.